# Meteor incrementally loads data on refresh, but not on route

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor application, and among other things, it does a count of a collection on the client side. When I refresh the page, I see the count incrementally increase - it slowly ticks up from 0 to 3000. I assume this is because the data is published incrementally.

However, when I route to the same page from another, it waits for the data which takes a few seconds, and then the number 3000 appears. My guess is that it has do with several large queries being waited upon before the page renders, when the data is already completely published. The subscription manager package does not solve the problem by caching the data, which supports my thoughts. But my tests only help so much.

How can I achieve the same incremental loading on routing?

Comment: use a template subscription. if you use IR's `waitOn` then it'll wait...

Comment: how do you change routes? do you use iron router or flow router?

Comment: Iron-router. 
@MattK, I do not want it to wait, I want the opposite. I want the page to load before the data is ready, and to have it display incrementally, as it does while the data is being published.

Comment: exactly, so you can't use the `waitOn` method. you'll have to turn on the subscription when the template is created